# Sorting Columns in Fiddler's *.saz _index.html file

Tags: fiddler

I have added a timestamp column which I can drag and drop to show on the left size.  However, when I generate the *.saz, in the _index.html file the timestamp column shows all the way on the right side.  I've gone through Fiddler's config files, but can't seem to find the column list anywhere.  Is there a way to have the timestamp column show on the left in the _index.html (aside from opening the file in a WYSIWYG editor and moving the column every time).

Thanks,
Kate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no way to configure the ordering of columns that Fiddler exports in the HTML index file.

Generally speaking, it's expected that the user will reload a SAZ file using Fiddler itself.